# How I can update the new Environment purpose for existing TtmCdTopologyType in SDLWeb8

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I already created the TtmCdTopologyType with "wip" EnvironmentPurpose as shown in below which is fine.

```
Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id TestToplogyType -Name "CMS5 TargetType" -EnvironmentPurposes “wip"
```

How I can update above TestToplogyType by adding one more "Staging" Purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set-TtmCdTopologyType` command to update the existing type.

**Updated**

`Set-TtmCdTopologyType -Id TestToplogyType -Name "TestTargetType" -EnvironmentPurposes @('Release','Approved')`

Refer [table](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3BD6ED93-41B7-4357-92DB-8AEA8DEFB0A1)

[how to use](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/finding-your-way-around-the-sdl-web-8-cmdlets)

Comment: Thanks it's working fine.                                                                           Set-TtmCdTopologyType -Id TestToplogyType -Name "TestTargetType" -EnvironmentPurposes @('Release','Approved')

Comment: How about updating discovery endpoint url's for both purposes at one time.      Is below syntax is correct ?                                                                                                Set-TtmCdEnvironment -Id TestCD -EnvironmentPurpose @('Release','Approved') -DiscoveryEndpointUrl @("http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc","http://localhost:8092/discovery.svc")

Comment: No, you can't update multiple CD Environments with one `Set-TtmCdEnvironment` cmdlet invocation.

Comment: You might find [this reference topic of available PowerShell scripts](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3BD6ED93-41B7-4357-92DB-8AEA8DEFB0A1) useful.